# itertools.izip (and _longest) dictionary incomplete

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I'm using Python itertools to zip two lists into a dictionary. The first list contains 63 single character strings, while the second list contains contains 63 lists all containing 63 single character strings.

A single entry of the completed dictionary should look something like this:

```
{'S': ['X', 'D', '2', 'Y', 'd', 'K', '6', '0', '1', 'S', '9', 's', 'm', 'b', 't', 'k', 'G', 'j', 'n', 'v', 'O', 'x', 'U', 'h', 'P', 'B', 'V', 'C', '4', 'N', 'g', 'T', 'H', 'F', 'q', 'y', 'L', 'E', '3', '8', '5', 'A', 'a', 'W', 'o', 'w', 'c', 'r', 'z', 'Space', '7', 'p', 'I', 'e', 'u', 'f', 'Z', 'R', 'M', 'i', 'Q', 'l', 'J']}
```

The length of each list to be zipped is 63, but the dictionary that is returned is always varies between 36 and 45 and never reaches the full amount of 63.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
def obfuscation(character_list):    
    print('Building cipher, please wait...')
    import itertools
    import random
    assigned_list = character_list
    cipher_list = []
    cipher_reference = []    
    for item in character_list:
        random.shuffle(assigned_list)        
        cipher_list.append(assigned_list)
        cipher_reference.append(item)        

    print(len(cipher_reference))
    print(len(cipher_list)) 
    cipher = dict(itertools.izip_longest(cipher_reference, cipher_list))
    raw_input(len(cipher))
    return cipher
```

Returns:

```
Building cipher, please wait...
63
63
41
```

Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Your single-entry example is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: There still is a `, '1']` at the end that is invalid.

Comment: You are *shuffling* `character_list` while looping over it, and appending the list *itself* each iteration. That means that `cipher_list` contains `len(character_list)` copies of `character_list`, all the same, shuffled `len(character_list)` times.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, see edited code. I had actually created a list copy beforehand and removed it thinking it was a pointless copy. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @vbiqvitovs: That's not a copy either, that's just another reference to the same list. Use `list(other_list)` or `other_list[:]` to create a **new** list object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's a sad, ignorant misunderstanding on my part. I should have understood that by now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reshuffling `character_list` while iterating over it, and appending *references* to the same list to `cipher_list` each time. That means there is now `len(character_list)` references to *the same list* added to `cipher_list`.

As a result of the constant reshuffling, your are adding *duplicates* to `cipher_list` as well, which is why your resulting dictionary has fewer than 63 keys.

If you wanted to create 63 randomized copies of `character_list`, plus 64th single list of the same list, use this instead:

```
def obfuscation(character_list):    
    return {k: sorted(character_list, key=lambda k: random.random()) for k in character_list}
```

This creates a dictionary with `len(character_list)` keys, each a randomized *copy* of `character_list`. Dictionaries have no ordering, so the input for that dict comprehension needs no shuffling itself.

`sorted()` takes a key function to determine how to compare values, by using `random.random` the returned list is in random order.

This produces:

```
>>> res = obfuscation(character_list)
>>> res
{'Space': ['P', '4', '8', 'w', 'i', '1', 'q', '0', 'F', 'n', '2', 'm', 'U', 'R', 'E', 'V', 'j', 'A', '6', 'K', 'o', 'l', 'x', 'Q', 'y', 'Space', 'L', 'g', 'B', 't', 'e', 'r', 'X', 'D', 'k', 'Y', 'f', 'G', 'H', 'O', 'Z', 'v', 'J', 'p', 'u', 's', 'd', 'N', 'c', '9', 'z', 'W', '3', 'a', 'h', 'b', 'C', '7', 'I', 'S', '5', 'M', 'T'], '1': ['9', '7', '2', 'G', 'C', 'I', 'S', 'v', 'b', 'O', 'W', 'L', 'R', 'k', 'f', 'K', 'e', 'y', 'u', 'J', 'q', 'T', 'V', '5', '8', 'x', 't', 'D', 'w', 'g', 'M', 'N', 'X', 'z', 'a', 'A', 'Q', 'Space', 'r', 'i', 'l', 'B', 'n', '1', 'c', 's', 'Y', 'm', 'P', 'p', 'Z', 'd', 'E', '6', 'H', 'h', 'o', '4', 'j', '0', '3', 'F', 'U'], '0': ['B', 'a', '5', 'o', 'd', 'g', '9', 'Y', '2', 'z', 'p', '4', 'W', 'r', 'R', 'f', '1', 'c', 'e', 'Z', 'D', 'l', 'u', '6', 'y', 'H', 'O', '7', 'T', 'Q', 'n', 'k', 'P', 'v', 'F', 'w', 'C', 'E', '3', 'Space', 'I', 'i', 'j', 'q', 'b', 'A', '0', 'J', 'S', 'N', 't', 'U', 's', 'L', 'm', 'X', '8', 'K', 'G', 'V', 'M', 'x', 'h'], '3': ['r', '1', 'L', 'R', 'F', 'X', 'y', '6', '2', 'S', 's', 'b', 'a', 'J', 'x', 'i', 'm', 'Z', 'l', '0', 'N', 'U', 'I', 'd', 'v', 'O', 'n', 'P', 'W', 'q', '4', 'k', '3', 'D', 'C', 'Q', '5', 'f', 'K', 'o', 'g', '9', '7', 'Space', 'G', 'B', 'p', 'V', 'c', 'e', 'T', 'A', 'j', 'Y', 'H', 'E', 't', 'M', 'z', 'u', 'w', 'h', '8'], '2': ['v', 'Q', 'S', 'P', '9', 'l', 'X', 'H', 'z', 'q', '1', 'M', 'C', 'a', 'y', 'V', '5', 'N', 'Z', 't', 'x', 'K', '0', 'A', 'i', 'u', 'T', 'c', 'e', 'j', 'Y', '8', 'I', 'F', 'g', 'U', 's', 'k', 'w', 'W', 'h', 'J', 'O', 'o', 'm', 'D', 'L', '6', 'E', 'r', '2', 'G', 'f', 'd', 'R', 'p', 'n', 'b', '3', '4', 'Space', '7', 'B'], '5': ['i', 'O', 'T', 'I', 'v', 'o', 'H', 'k', 'n', 'C', 'G', '8', '5', '0', 'Z', 'J', 'm', 'j', 'l', 'S', 'B', 'f', '3', 'M', 'E', '7', 'V', 'x', '6', 'L', '4', 'A', 'P', 'q', 'Y', 'Space', 'D', 'Q', 'r', 'g', 'b', 'X', 'W', 'd', 'u', 'h', 'p', 's', '2', 'a', 'e', '9', 'c', 'z', '1', 't', 'R', 'N', 'y', 'K', 'F', 'w', 'U'], '4': ['h', 'f', 'I', 'T', 'd', 'D', 'X', 's', '3', 't', 'Q', 'e', '4', 'S', 'P', 'B', 'H', 'N', 'p', '6', 'm', 'K', 'V', 'i', 'F', 'M', 'k', 'r', 'u', 'z', 'A', 'a', 'v', 'C', 'O', 'c', 'q', 'w', 'n', 'g', 'j', 'Z', 'o', 'G', '2', 'W', '8', 'x', '5', 'Y', 'J', 'l', 'Space', 'R', 'L', '9', '7', 'b', 'U', '1', 'y', 'E', '0'], '7': ['j', 'W', 'F', 'T', 'V', 'L', '5', 'A', '9', '0', 'q', '4', 'R', 'E', 'r', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'H', 'e', 'J', 'C', 'v', 'p', 'b', 'K', 'Space', 'l', 't', 'd', 'G', 'u', 'U', '6', 'x', 'S', 's', 'k', 'w', '3', 'z', 'm', 'P', 'X', 'D', '7', 'Z', 'i', 'y', 'g', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'o', '8', 'O', '1', 'M', 'a', 'I', 'f', 'Y', '2'], '6': ['i', '9', 'x', 'b', 'Space', 'o', 'P', 'y', 'h', 'z', 'H', '3', 'U', 'B', '7', '8', 'E', 'm', 'R', 'k', 'D', '0', 'Z', 'S', 'G', 's', 'X', 'W', 'p', 'n', 'N', 'w', 'c', 'q', '4', 'j', 'M', 'A', 'J', 'l', 'd', 'Y', 'v', '5', 't', 'g', '6', 'a', 'f', 'e', 'F', '2', 'K', 'u', '1', 'O', 'r', 'T', 'V', 'L', 'Q', 'I', 'C'], '9': ['H', 'I', 'P', 'p', 'K', 'E', 'f', 'e', 'i', 'C', 'd', '1', 'j', '5', '9', '2', 'c', 'R', 'J', '4', 'X', 'M', 'l', 'G', 'r', 'B', 'A', 'z', 'F', 't', 'k', 'w', 'Q', 'a', 'o', '7', 'W', 'O', 'L', 'b', '0', 'T', 'Y', 'q', 'x', 'Z', 'm', 'g', 'U', 'v', 'u', 'D', 'n', 'Space', '6', 'N', 'V', 'h', 'y', 'S', 's', '3', '8'], '8': ['7', 'z', 'D', 'j', 'J', 'A', 'K', 'M', 'N', 'n', '1', 'r', 'm', 'X', 'L', 'l', 'e', 'R', '8', 'h', 't', '6', '5', 'F', 'Space', 'x', 'H', 'P', '9', 'i', 'Y', 'u', 'Z', 'v', 'f', 'q', '3', 'W', 's', 'p', 'y', 'T', 'a', 'b', 'V', 'g', 'c', 'Q', 'U', '0', 'I', 'd', 'E', 'O', 'B', 'w', 'G', 'C', 'k', 'o', 'S', '2', '4'], 'A': ['I', 'Q', 'd', 'r', 'T', 'X', 'i', 'B', 'Z', 'P', 'G', 'u', '1', 'v', 'D', '6', 'W', 'q', 'e', '2', 'V', 'U', 'S', 'h', 'R', 'E', '0', 'f', 'b', 't', 'C', 'k', 'x', 'p', 'y', 'M', '7', 'A', 'c', 'H', 'g', 'J', 'O', 'l', '8', '4', 'F', 'Space', '9', 'w', 'o', 'K', '5', 'j', 'n', 'a', 'Y', 'L', '3', 's', 'm', 'N', 'z'], 'C': ['3', 'd', 'r', 'M', 't', 'L', 'l', 'V', 'o', 'R', 'n', 'P', 'T', 'q', 'Q', 'z', 's', 'j', 'Space', '4', '5', 'H', 'c', 'b', 'Z', 'C', '6', 'g', 'w', 'U', 'y', 'X', 'D', '2', 'I', 'm', 'B', 'G', 'f', 'a', 'A', '8', 'e', '1', 'i', 'K', 'F', 'Y', 'v', '0', 'x', 'p', 'u', 'k', 'J', 'h', 'N', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'O', '7', '9'], 'B': ['w', 'p', '6', 'm', 'v', 'u', '9', 'y', '7', 'Y', 'e', 'F', 'i', 'C', 'd', 'H', 'U', 'b', '5', 'B', 'c', 'a', 'A', 'D', 'X', 'o', 'q', 'V', 'G', 'N', 'I', 'P', 'Q', '2', 'f', 'l', 'J', '0', 'M', 'k', 'Space', '8', 'Z', 's', 'L', 'j', 'O', 'n', 'K', 'h', 'W', '1', '4', 'E', 'r', 'S', '3', 't', 'x', 'z', 'g', 'R', 'T'], 'E': ['q', 'o', 'w', '9', 'N', 'V', 'a', 'm', '5', 'Y', 'M', 'U', '0', 'z', 'Space', '8', 'B', 'i', 'T', 'C', 'P', 'Q', 'Z', 'J', 'A', 'H', 'g', 'n', 's', 'S', '1', 'e', 'f', '3', '6', 'b', 'K', 'L', 'O', 'X', 'G', 'd', 'k', 'c', '2', 'p', 'y', 'v', 'D', '4', 'W', 'h', 'E', 'u', 'j', 'F', 'I', 'l', 'x', '7', 't', 'r', 'R'], 'D': ['Y', 't', 'F', 'o', 'g', 'K', 'i', 'w', '8', 'N', 'O', 'j', 'R', 'Q', 'e', 'u', 'G', 'd', 'h', 'I', 'H', 'E', 'C', 'X', 'J', 'B', '4', 'v', 'y', 'p', '5', 'f', 'A', 'M', 'm', 'Space', 'V', 'z', 'U', 'W', 'L', 'c', 'x', 'S', 's', '2', '6', '0', '1', 'P', 'l', 'k', 'b', 'a', 'T', '9', 'q', 'r', 'Z', 'D', '3', '7', 'n'], 'G': ['u', 'j', 'L', 'B', '7', 'M', 'D', '9', 'k', 'p', 'v', 'A', 'G', 't', 'Y', 'P', 'f', 'E', 'b', 'F', '0', '1', 'g', 'c', 'K', 'W', 'e', 'H', '3', '2', 'w', 'i', 'X', 'V', 'o', 'N', 'q', 'h', 'Z', 'l', 'd', '5', 'I', '8', 'Q', 'Space', 'z', 'a', 'x', 'R', 'J', 'O', 'y', 'r', 'C', '4', 'n', 'm', 'U', 'T', 's', 'S', '6'], 'F': ['Y', 'F', 'R', 'c', 'E', 'z', 'W', 'i', 'm', 'y', 'Space', 'r', 'L', 'v', '0', '9', 'M', 'O', 'e', 'V', 'b', 'P', 'J', 'q', 'l', '8', 'G', 'T', 'U', 'S', 'h', 'k', '1', 'a', 'Z', 'X', '2', 'I', 'B', '4', 's', 'D', 't', 'N', 'A', 'w', '5', 'K', 'H', 'x', 'f', 'g', '6', 'C', 'Q', 'j', '7', 'n', 'o', '3', 'd', 'u', 'p'], 'I': ['r', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'Q', 'Z', '6', '3', '5', 'g', 'o', 'v', 'l', 'w', 'Space', 's', 'B', 'a', 'X', 'C', 'u', 'R', 'z', 'P', 'F', 'L', 'x', 'f', 'U', '4', '7', 'p', 'T', 'Y', 'K', '0', 'n', 'V', 'b', 'k', 'S', 'I', 'm', 'J', 'q', 'M', 'W', '2', 'y', 'G', '1', '8', 'h', 'E', 'e', 'O', 'D', 'N', 't', 'H', 'A', '9', 'j'], 'H': ['B', 't', '9', 'Y', 'X', '7', 'V', 'Space', '2', 'E', 'm', 's', 'l', 'D', 'e', 'd', '5', 'L', 'f', 'x', 'I', 'h', '1', 'J', 'P', 'u', 'F', 'H', 'K', 'C', 'o', 'Z', 'W', 'n', 'w', 'q', 'g', 'G', '6', 'U', '8', 'c', 'N', 'a', 'A', 'O', 'y', 'v', '3', 'R', 'Q', 'j', 'i', '0', 'T', 'p', '4', 'S', 'b', 'z', 'M', 'r', 'k'], 'K': ['Z', 'i', 'n', 'u', 'V', 'G', '9', 'F', '6', 'N', 'd', 'x', 'f', 'c', 'Q', 'Space', 'e', 'h', 'r', 'C', 'Y', 'U', 'o', '5', 'y', 'k', 'J', 'D', 'a', 'I', '3', 'X', 'H', 'O', '8', 's', '7', 'v', 'S', 'K', 'w', 'z', 'm', 'g', 'A', 'L', 'j', 'T', '1', 'R', 't', 'q', '2', 'M', 'W', 'l', '4', 'b', 'p', 'B', 'P', 'E', '0'], 'J': ['5', 'm', 'J', 'W', 'Q', '9', 'j', 'O', 'g', 'V', 'D', 'd', 'Space', 'E', 'l', 'N', '7', '3', 'k', 'L', 'M', 'v', '8', 'R', 'o', '6', 'B', 'G', 'w', 'a', 'Z', 'X', 'I', 'i', 'x', 'y', 't', 'U', 'K', 'H', '2', 'T', 'b', '0', 's', 'A', 'f', 'P', '1', 'n', 'p', 'e', 'F', 'C', 'u', '4', 'c', 'z', 'Y', 'S', 'q', 'h', 'r'], 'M': ['e', 'g', 'H', '1', 'T', '0', 'C', 'J', '6', 'z', 'B', 'y', 'h', 'V', 'F', 'k', 'G', 'R', '5', 'q', 'w', 'O', 'U', '7', 'j', 'f', '3', 'I', 'Y', 'E', 'M', 'n', 'x', 'u', 'Space', 't', 'c', '2', 'v', 'Z', '4', 'r', 'L', 'W', 'X', 'i', 'N', 's', 'D', 'p', 'K', 'A', '8', 'a', 'l', 'd', '9', 'Q', 'S', 'b', 'o', 'P', 'm'], 'L': ['g', 'W', 'z', 'Y', '3', 'O', 'D', 'V', 'A', 'K', 't', 'T', 'B', 'U', 's', 'p', 'Space', 'f', 'k', 'v', 'c', 'C', 'j', 'x', 'E', 'm', 'L', 'P', 'r', '0', 'S', 'e', '9', 'Z', '2', 'w', 'd', 'R', 'h', 'i', '1', 'u', 'a', '7', 'y', '6', 'M', 'H', 'o', '5', '8', 'q', 'n', 'X', 'b', 'Q', 'G', 'F', '4', 'N', 'I', 'J', 'l'], 'O': ['c', 'p', 'G', 'e', 'x', 'b', '5', 'z', 'g', 'A', 'O', 'n', '2', 'P', 'I', 'N', 'y', 'm', '3', 't', 'h', 'T', 'a', 'H', '6', 'M', '0', 'Y', 'd', '7', '4', 'w', 'L', '1', 'X', 'W', 'i', 'F', '8', 'C', 'u', 'R', 'r', 'j', 'V', 'v', 'S', 'D', 's', 'Space', 'Q', 'B', '9', 'q', 'o', 'K', 'U', 'l', 'k', 'Z', 'J', 'f', 'E'], 'N': ['H', 'Z', '6', 'G', 'j', 'D', 'E', 'U', 'h', 'e', 'c', 'z', '4', 'R', 'q', 'K', 'n', '9', 'u', 'Space', 'M', 's', 'i', 'J', 'X', '5', 'A', 'l', 'k', 'L', '0', 'Y', '7', 'p', 'b', 't', 'P', 'B', 'f', 'S', 'F', 'N', 'm', 'g', '1', 'w', 'C', '2', 'y', 'T', 'x', 'Q', '3', 'I', 'v', 'O', 'r', 'a', '8', 'd', 'o', 'W', 'V'], 'Q': ['i', 'l', 'G', 'h', 'I', 'Space', 'Q', 'y', 'B', 'W', 'w', 'Y', '2', 'u', '5', '4', 'z', 'm', '6', '9', 'n', 'P', '0', 'H', 'Z', 'r', 'a', 'v', 'A', 'j', 'U', 'f', 'c', 'N', 'x', 's', 'M', 't', 'L', 'R', 'E', '1', 'C', 'k', 'T', 'q', 'X', '8', 'V', 'p', 'K', '7', 'J', 'S', 'b', 'O', 'o', 'D', 'e', '3', 'g', 'F', 'd'], 'P': ['o', 'A', 'l', 'w', 'p', 'n', 'h', '5', 'm', 'H', 'Z', '0', 'F', 'Q', 'V', 'f', 'J', 'P', 'L', 'T', 'j', '6', 'B', 'e', 'E', '3', 'S', 'r', '1', 'Y', 'y', 'd', 'Space', 'z', '4', 's', 'q', 'O', 'C', '8', 'N', 'u', 'R', 't', 'g', 'k', 'I', 'v', 'a', 'W', 'X', 'x', 'G', 'i', 'M', '7', '2', 'c', 'K', 'D', 'b', '9', 'U'], 'S': ['a', 'b', 'r', '4', 'Space', 'O', 'P', 'o', '8', 'T', 'f', 'K', '9', '7', 'R', 'F', 's', 'm', 'Y', 'J', 'X', '6', 'k', 'z', 'E', '0', 'B', 'G', 'y', 'S', 'q', 'A', 'M', 'h', 'H', 'I', 'C', '5', 'd', '1', 't', 'e', 'w', 'L', 'j', 'N', 'D', 'n', 'c', '2', 'V', 'v', 'u', 'l', 'U', 'i', 'p', 'g', 'Z', '3', 'W', 'Q', 'x'], 'R': ['f', 'E', 'T', 'P', 'j', 's', '9', 'h', '1', 'e', '3', 'W', 'I', 'S', '2', 'J', 'u', '0', 'x', 'y', 'a', '7', 'Z', 'w', 'l', 'V', 'b', 'c', 'Y', 't', 'm', 'v', 'r', 'Space', 'K', 'G', 'O', 'L', '6', 'H', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'A', 'D', 'i', '4', 'd', 'n', 'C', 'B', 'F', 'R', '8', 'g', 'M', 'z', 'U', 'Q', 'k', 'N', 'X', '5'], 'U': ['u', 'k', 'N', 'R', 'W', 'g', 'E', 'K', 'I', 'j', 'P', 'C', 'L', 'Y', 'y', 'm', 'H', 'b', 'F', '8', 'Space', 'a', 'r', 'J', 'S', 'd', 'Q', 'e', 'i', 'w', 'X', 'c', '6', 'v', 'h', 'A', 'D', 'x', 'O', 't', 'G', 's', 'z', 'q', 'p', 'l', 'B', '2', '9', 'Z', 'o', 'f', '1', 'V', '5', 'U', '7', 'T', 'M', '4', '3', 'n', '0'], 'T': ['B', 'A', 'v', '7', 's', 'U', 'u', 'o', 'T', 'i', 'q', 'b', 'F', '1', 'l', '5', 'G', 'S', 'm', 'C', '0', 'k', 'a', 'I', 'r', 'Y', 'h', 'Space', 'g', '3', 'H', 'J', 'f', 'd', 'V', 'Q', 'E', 'c', 'O', 'D', 'e', '4', 'x', 'P', '9', 'M', 'Z', 'R', 'y', 'L', 'K', 'j', '6', 'z', 't', 'p', '2', 'N', 'n', 'W', 'w', '8', 'X'], 'W': ['9', 'D', 'F', 'B', 'Space', 'Z', 'W', 'm', '8', 'o', 'Y', 'd', 'H', 'l', 'q', 'i', 'R', 'e', 'T', 'J', 'S', 'E', 'L', 'h', 'I', '7', 't', 'Q', 'N', 'M', 'X', 'f', 'x', 'w', 'y', 'G', '3', 'v', 'C', 'U', 'b', 'p', 'c', '0', 'r', 'z', '6', 'n', 'V', 'j', '4', 'k', 'g', 'a', '2', 's', '1', 'u', 'K', 'O', 'P', 'A', '5'], 'V': ['x', 'A', 'V', 'R', 'j', 'c', 'w', '1', '6', 'G', 'a', 'H', 'Space', 'J', '3', 'X', 't', 'N', 'E', 'k', 'h', 'u', 'r', 'W', 'Z', 's', 'p', 'D', 'C', 'O', '7', 'm', 'e', 'Q', 'b', 'U', 'S', 'P', 'l', 'Y', 'o', 'M', '4', 'I', 'n', '5', 'i', 'L', 'g', 'f', '9', 'd', '0', 'y', '8', 'q', 'v', 'F', 'B', 'K', 'z', 'T', '2'], 'Y': ['e', 'O', 'p', 'N', 'P', 'L', 'c', 'H', 's', 'g', 'S', 'V', 'y', 'w', '1', 'J', 'D', 'W', 'b', 'k', 'h', 'I', 'G', 'q', 'T', 'o', 'u', 'K', 'E', 'n', 'j', 'l', '7', 'v', 'X', 'Y', 'f', 'Space', '5', 'r', '9', '2', 't', '4', 'x', 'Q', 'Z', 'z', 'M', 'i', '6', 'A', 'R', '3', 'd', 'F', 'a', 'U', 'B', 'm', 'C', '0', '8'], 'X': ['k', 'S', 'l', 'E', '0', 'L', 'I', '5', 'Y', 'p', 'O', 'v', 'g', 'U', 's', '9', 'j', '4', 'a', 'q', 'D', 'b', 'C', '1', 'P', 'w', 'y', 'H', 'Q', 'Space', 'h', 'u', 'W', 'f', 'x', 'K', 'R', '7', 'M', 'J', 'A', '3', 'X', 'z', '8', 'e', 'B', '6', 'r', 'G', 'T', 'i', 'F', 'c', '2', 'N', 't', 'm', 'Z', 'n', 'V', 'd', 'o'], 'Z': ['j', '9', 'O', 'X', 'l', 'Y', 'p', '8', 'y', 'I', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'v', 'D', 'S', 'w', 'f', 'Space', 'R', 'V', 'k', 'd', 'u', '4', 'o', 'K', 'm', '5', 'q', 'Q', '2', '3', 'z', 'a', 's', 'F', 'c', 'x', 'W', 'B', 'i', 'Z', 'g', 't', 'E', '0', 'N', 'M', 'h', '7', '1', 'r', 'U', 'L', 'H', 'n', 'b', 'P', '6', 'e', 'J'], 'a': ['8', 'x', '1', 'c', 'r', 'y', 'd', '9', 'C', 'u', '0', 'p', 'J', '5', 'D', 'K', 'A', 'F', 'e', '6', 'H', 't', 'P', 'O', 'v', 'L', 'G', 'l', 'f', 'o', 'T', 'N', 'j', 'n', '3', 'z', 'S', 'Space', 'Z', 'I', '2', 'g', 'V', '4', 'k', 's', 'a', 'R', 'B', 'w', 'q', 'i', 'b', 'E', 'U', 'Y', '7', 'X', 'm', 'Q', 'W', 'M', 'h'], 'c': ['N', 'K', 't', 'j', 'J', '7', 'r', 'A', 'C', 'S', 'Z', 'a', 'G', 'i', 'D', 'm', 'v', 'M', 'c', 'l', 'n', 'x', 'q', '5', 'e', '2', '4', 'w', 'h', 'V', '8', 'z', 'g', '0', '9', 's', 'u', 'k', 'o', 'L', 'E', 'b', '3', 'R', 'f', 'd', '1', 'H', 'O', 'U', 'T', '6', 'P', 'Q', 'X', 'Y', 'W', 'Space', 'y', 'p', 'I', 'B', 'F'], 'b': ['L', 'Y', 'i', 'y', 'w', 'E', 'X', 'a', '7', 'u', 'c', 'B', 'v', 'N', 'r', 'Z', 'f', 'C', '1', 'W', 'b', 'T', 'q', 'Q', 'P', 'g', 'j', '2', '9', 'O', '6', 'H', 'e', 'V', '4', 'n', 'l', 'z', 'p', 'd', 'h', 'D', 'S', 'Space', 'x', 'm', 'M', '3', 'G', '5', 'F', '8', 'K', 'U', '0', 'A', 'J', 't', 's', 'o', 'R', 'I', 'k'], 'e': ['Z', 'k', 'l', '9', 'M', '4', 'y', 'U', 'a', 'Y', '1', 'A', 'g', '3', 'C', 'W', 'B', 's', 'd', '0', 'H', 'D', 'b', 'S', 'N', 'L', 'J', '8', 'j', 'Space', 'P', 'f', 'K', 'c', 'h', 'Q', 'v', 'z', 'i', 'G', '7', 'F', '6', 'p', 'n', 'r', 'e', 'I', 'R', 'V', 'T', 'w', 'q', 'E', 'm', 'X', 't', 'u', 'O', 'o', 'x', '5', '2'], 'd': ['7', 'N', 'k', 'Z', 'w', 'l', 'X', 'e', 'H', '5', 'a', 'I', 'v', 'm', 'n', 'D', 'O', 'g', '6', '4', 'V', 'B', 'b', 'G', 't', 'F', 'u', 'U', '1', 'd', 'z', 'Space', 'T', 'y', 'S', 'j', 'q', 'r', 'Q', 's', 'x', '9', 'C', '8', 'A', 'h', 'o', 'L', 'i', 'E', 'J', '3', 'c', 'R', 'Y', '0', 'K', 'p', 'M', 'f', 'P', 'W', '2'], 'g': ['E', 'i', 'a', 's', 'e', 'J', 'g', '3', 'Z', 'R', 'c', 'u', 'O', '5', 'v', 'T', 'b', 'B', 'L', 'F', 'q', 'x', 'Space', 'W', 'n', 'H', '9', 'D', 'V', '6', 'm', 'j', '7', 'l', 'A', 'U', 'h', '8', 'k', 'w', 'S', 'K', 't', '1', 'Y', '4', 'G', 'M', 'X', '0', 'z', 'f', 'r', 'y', 'C', 'P', 'N', 'o', 'Q', 'I', 'p', 'd', '2'], 'f': ['I', 'N', 'O', 'a', '6', 'b', 'j', 'Z', '0', 'e', '8', 'A', 'C', 'Q', 'F', 'H', '9', '5', '1', 'U', 'k', 'T', 'K', 'h', 'L', 's', '2', 'l', '3', 'B', 'q', 'r', 'c', 'J', 'g', 'i', 'S', 'd', 'v', 'G', 'Y', 'n', 'x', 'V', 'M', 'D', 'R', 'z', '7', 'p', 'X', 'Space', 'P', 'y', 'u', 'f', 'w', 'm', 'W', 't', '4', 'o', 'E'], 'i': ['5', 'B', 'S', 'Y', 'q', 't', 'o', '9', '0', 'm', 'l', 'z', 'i', 'V', 'W', '6', 'D', 'r', '4', 'T', 'G', 'e', 'y', 'P', 'A', 'u', 's', 'L', 'k', 'Z', '7', 'R', 'J', 'h', '3', '2', 'd', 'X', 'j', 'b', '1', 'M', 'v', 'Q', 'O', 'U', 'Space', 'E', 'I', 'g', 'c', 'x', 'n', 'C', 'H', 'K', 'f', 'w', 'a', 'F', '8', 'p', 'N'], 'h': ['C', 'i', 'q', '1', 'n', 'a', 'P', 'p', '7', 'e', 'E', 'k', 'h', 'N', '5', 'm', 'B', 'Y', '2', 't', 'b', 'l', 'w', 'D', 'V', 'X', 'R', 'o', 'F', 'J', 'I', '8', 'H', 'K', 'z', 'r', 'U', 'O', '3', 'x', 'Space', 'j', 'v', 'S', 'A', '6', '9', 'c', 'M', 'T', 'G', 'Q', 's', 'd', 'W', 'y', 'f', 'Z', 'u', 'L', 'g', '0', '4'], 'k': ['A', 'r', 'h', 'c', 'm', 'F', 'f', 'v', 'G', 'k', 'i', 'E', 'l', 'X', 'j', 'Q', '5', 'p', 'b', 'T', 'q', 'w', 'e', 'o', 'D', 'Y', '3', 'd', 'W', 'Space', 'C', 'U', '1', 'g', '0', 'Z', 'M', '8', 'u', 'S', 'I', 'O', '6', 't', '9', 'y', 'R', 'J', '4', 'L', 'V', 'N', 's', 'a', 'z', 'B', 'P', 'H', 'K', 'n', '2', '7', 'x'], 'j': ['s', 'g', 'U', '5', 'M', 'n', '3', 'F', 'm', 'E', 'v', 'a', 'J', 'b', 'S', 'd', '7', 'e', 'H', 'u', 't', 'B', 'Space', 'I', 'T', 'k', 'K', 'N', 'V', 'q', '0', 'X', 'y', 'p', 'f', 'D', 'h', 'Q', '4', 'i', 'w', 'G', 'O', 'P', '6', 'R', 'C', 'c', 'L', 'Z', 'z', 'r', 'j', 'A', 'l', '1', '2', 'W', 'o', 'x', '8', 'Y', '9'], 'm': ['a', 't', 'J', '3', 'N', 'l', '6', 'e', 'Space', 'Q', 'D', 'I', 'P', 'd', 'u', '7', 'A', 'X', 'q', '9', 'g', 'T', 'n', '8', 'L', 'Y', 'Z', 'O', 'j', 'h', '0', 'b', 'M', 's', 'z', '2', 'F', 'E', 'v', 'y', 'i', 'm', '5', 'x', '1', 'r', 'H', 'k', 'G', 'p', 'W', 'o', 'K', 'w', 'B', 'R', '4', 'C', 'S', 'U', 'f', 'c', 'V'], 'l': ['Space', 'V', '7', 'Z', 'P', 'O', 'f', 'N', 'F', 'A', 't', 'k', 'o', 'X', 'i', '1', 'K', 'l', '6', 'J', 'n', 'h', 'q', 'Y', 'Q', 'r', 'H', '4', 'v', '2', 'w', 'b', 'y', 'G', '0', 'B', 'L', 'x', '5', 'z', 'j', 'T', 'e', 'u', 'g', 'U', '9', 'C', 'a', 's', 'M', 'p', 'm', 'W', '3', 'c', 'R', 'D', '8', 'E', 'd', 'I', 'S'], 'o': ['0', 'j', 'g', 'J', 'Q', 'T', 'B', 'm', 'E', 't', 'Z', 'Space', 'V', 'y', 'p', '2', 'S', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'r', 'H', 'N', 'X', 'L', 'i', 'k', 'h', '6', 'W', 'w', 'M', 'v', '5', 'K', 'e', '9', '4', 'b', 'O', 'F', 'x', 'u', 'l', 'o', 'd', 'Y', 'n', 'G', 'c', 'q', 'U', 'z', 'f', '1', 's', '8', '7', 'P', 'I', 'a', '3', 'R'], 'n': ['z', 'j', 'm', 'd', 'h', 'a', '5', 'D', 'r', 'o', '7', 'e', 'Z', 'M', 'P', 'L', 'Space', 'w', 'H', 'Y', 'J', 'b', 'n', 'p', '3', 's', 'U', 'B', '9', 'F', 'O', 'q', 'i', 'c', 'I', 'G', 'K', 'f', 'u', '8', '1', '4', 'y', 'W', 'S', 'R', 'X', 'V', 'k', 'A', '6', '2', 'Q', '0', 'l', 'E', 'T', 'g', 'x', 'v', 'N', 't', 'C'], 'q': ['J', 'W', 'f', 'r', 'q', 'V', 'v', 'Space', 'o', 'R', 'U', 'C', 'P', 'F', 'T', '7', 'G', 'O', 'e', 'p', 'A', 'L', 'x', 'Z', 'j', 'a', 'd', 'K', 'B', 'Q', 'N', 'm', 'S', 'y', 'b', 'i', 'X', 'h', '1', '0', 'I', 'D', 's', 'H', 'w', 'k', 'z', '6', '5', '2', 'c', 'n', 'M', 'u', '9', 'l', '8', 'E', 'g', '3', '4', 't', 'Y'], 'p': ['9', 'K', 's', 'S', 'n', '0', 'k', 'u', 'Q', 'M', 'Z', 'h', 'x', 'T', 'm', 'Space', 'N', 'r', 'D', 'z', 'g', 'X', 'U', 'b', 'd', '1', 'e', 'G', 'V', 'p', 'O', 'w', '2', 'B', 'J', 'H', 'I', 'F', 'i', '7', 'o', '8', '5', '4', 'c', 'W', 'C', 'E', 'a', 'L', 'q', 'P', 'R', 'y', 'j', 't', '6', 'A', 'f', '3', 'l', 'Y', 'v'], 's': ['9', 'O', '1', 'Z', '3', 'N', 'd', 'Space', 'D', '7', 'n', 'X', 'b', 'T', '5', 'C', 'x', 'v', 'l', 'Y', 'f', 'M', '6', 'P', 'F', 'y', 'K', 't', 'A', 'h', 'c', 'm', 'g', '4', 'L', '8', 'p', 's', 'S', 'V', 'Q', 'r', 'w', 'U', 'q', 'E', 'H', 'a', 'J', 'I', 'u', '2', 'z', 'o', 'B', 'i', 'R', 'e', 'j', '0', 'k', 'G', 'W'], 'r': ['Z', 'B', 'U', '8', 'o', '5', '1', 'y', '9', '6', 'V', '4', 'p', 'j', 'e', 'z', 'L', '2', 'A', 'J', 'x', 'S', 'X', '3', 'I', 'k', 'w', 'W', 'v', 'C', 'u', 'K', 'r', 't', 'T', 'c', 'E', 'R', 'D', 'd', 'G', 'l', 'H', 'Y', 'Q', 'F', 'm', '0', 'n', 'i', 's', 'O', 'h', 'Space', 'q', 'a', 'P', 'b', '7', 'N', 'g', 'M', 'f'], 'u': ['7', 'u', 'n', 'L', 'P', 'c', 'K', 'C', 'z', 'p', 'k', 'R', 'j', 'b', 'Space', '3', 'D', 'g', 'V', 'S', 'W', 'X', 'T', '8', '5', 'm', 'U', 'e', 'l', 'Q', '9', 'M', 'I', 'o', 'h', 'q', 'G', 'F', 'y', 'E', 'f', '0', 'Z', '4', 'Y', 'N', 's', 'x', 'B', '6', 'A', 'a', '1', '2', 'r', 't', 'v', 'd', 'O', 'i', 'H', 'w', 'J'], 't': ['J', 'u', 'B', 'f', '2', 'b', 'c', 't', 'W', 'L', 'q', 'H', '4', 'A', 'y', 'N', 'x', 'U', 'E', 'P', 'w', '0', 'a', 'G', 'j', 'o', 'h', '7', 'd', '9', 'K', '1', 'X', 'Q', 'Y', 'S', 'm', 'V', 'F', 'O', 'M', 'v', 'l', 'D', '6', 'k', 'C', 'n', '3', 'g', 'Z', 'r', 'T', 'e', 's', 'i', 'p', 'Space', 'R', '8', '5', 'I', 'z'], 'w': ['3', 'e', 'U', 'W', 'u', 'H', '2', '8', 'D', 'C', '6', 'j', 'k', 'O', 'M', 'E', 'X', 'Space', 'P', 'o', 'v', 'l', 'N', 'x', 'r', 'y', 'c', 'q', '0', 'G', 't', '1', 'd', 'T', 'Q', 'm', '7', '9', '4', 'V', 'A', 'n', 'p', '5', 'R', 'L', 'b', 'w', 'F', 'K', 'a', 'Z', 'I', 'Y', 'S', 'f', 'B', 'z', 'J', 'h', 's', 'g', 'i'], 'v': ['P', 'Space', 'A', 'l', 's', 'o', 'f', 'Y', 'M', 'n', 'b', 'm', 'v', '8', 'd', '3', 'T', '9', 'N', 'x', 'O', 'S', 'J', 'R', 'q', 'r', '6', 'F', 'p', 'k', 'H', '4', 'h', 't', 'G', 'W', '1', '2', 'j', 'z', 'V', 'e', 'u', 'C', 'X', 'a', 'g', 'I', 'K', 'y', '5', 'Z', 'i', 'E', 'c', 'B', 'L', 'w', '7', 'Q', '0', 'U', 'D'], 'y': ['k', 'u', 'a', 'H', 'J', 's', 'm', '5', 'p', 'g', 'Z', 'P', 'G', 'l', 'v', 'd', '0', 'W', 'B', '4', 'Y', 'z', '1', 'q', 'c', 'x', 'h', 'K', 'j', 'F', 'R', 'Space', 'U', 'r', 'n', 'N', 'w', 'b', 'C', 'y', '9', 'D', '7', '2', 'L', 'T', 'Q', 'i', 'o', '6', 'S', '3', 'f', 'X', 'O', 'V', 't', 'A', 'I', 'M', 'e', '8', 'E'], 'x': ['z', 'n', 'V', 'Space', 'y', 'Z', 'M', 'm', 'D', 'c', 'r', 's', 'J', 'v', '4', 'e', '7', 'W', '9', 'X', 'C', '6', 'U', 'G', 'o', 'i', 'f', 'u', 'N', 'k', 'B', 'b', 'K', 'E', 'w', 'h', 'H', 'Y', 'T', 'L', 'R', 'p', 'g', 'S', 'x', '0', 'j', 'I', '8', 'Q', '2', '3', '1', 'P', 'l', 'O', 'q', 't', 'd', 'F', 'a', 'A', '5'], 'z': ['w', 'J', 's', 't', 'I', 'r', 'N', 'i', 'Space', 'O', 'V', 'M', 'T', 'g', 'A', 'j', 'c', 'H', '9', 'e', '0', 'h', 'p', 'o', 'S', 'K', '4', 'f', '6', 'P', '2', 'R', '7', 'F', 'l', '8', 'L', 'Z', 'n', 'Q', 'u', 'E', 'z', 'q', 'G', '3', 'a', 'X', 'v', '5', 'Y', 'x', 'C', 'm', 'd', 'k', 'W', '1', 'y', 'B', 'D', 'b', 'U']}
>>> len(res)
63
>>> all(len(v) == 63 for v in res.values())
True
```

Comment: I added a comment shortly after your 2nd response. Each iterable within the character_list needs to have a single entry within the dictionary and an assigned randomized list (no copies allowed). Your random.random would provide copies of both, would it not?

Comment: @vbiqvitovs: No, each dictionary value is a unique randomized list.